# Difficulty to use cv2.adaptiveThreshold with the reflection problematic

Tags: python, opencv

**GOAL:** I need a cleaned image to use pytesseract and get the text from it.
I pass this image into gray.
I use `cv2.adaptiveThreshold` to deal with the reflection problematic. But it doesn't work well.
My text became less readable and pytesseract can't read it. I don't know how to upgrade my image.

[image: image evolution]

```
import cv2

path = "path/to/image.jpg"


rgb_img = cv2.imread(path)
gray_img = cv2.imread(path, 0)
tresholded_img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 19, 1)
cv2.imshow('rgb', rgb_img)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray_img)
cv2.imshow('tresholded', tresholded_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

EDIT:
`cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C` didn't gave me better result.
Here is a sample.

[image: img_1]
[image: img_2]
[image: img_3]
[image: img_4]

Comment: The problem is so dynamic. you'll have to experiment with various parameters for your dataset or image. try using gaussian based thresholding instead of mean, `cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255,
 cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,  19, 1)`                               And to remove noise in the image you'll need to use noise reduction techniques like **morphologial operations** . Please provide sample image for further testing.

Comment: here is an update of the post @AvishkaDambawinna

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/difficulty-to-use-cv2-adaptivethreshold-with-the-reflection-problematic/5832